# '((new System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugViewthrew an exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException'

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

here is my code I have function

```
public List<Questions_tbl> GetQuestions()
        {
  using (Question_answerEntities dc = new Question_answerEntities())
                    {
                        return dc.Questions_tbl.ToList();
                    }
}
```

I call this function from another one

```
  public string GetquestList()
        {        
            var list = NC.GetQuestions();   
        }
```

Question table contains list of answer table 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2diX.png) 
and see this exception

```
Answer_tbl = '((new System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView<Question_Answer_App_Task.Models.Questions_tbl>(list)).Items[0]).Answer_tbl' threw an exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException'
```

here is my class

```
 public partial class Questions_tbl
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Questions_tbl()
        {
            this.Answer_tbl = new HashSet<Answer_tbl>();
        }

        public long Quest_Id { get; set; }
        public string Quest_Body { get; set; }
        public long User_Id { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Answer_tbl> Answer_tbl { get; set; }
        public virtual User_tbl User_tbl { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: `Questions_tbl` has navigational or child properties which are configured to lazy load?

Comment: How can I know that? @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: Check the class.. Does it have all properties of primitive data types such as string, int, double etc? or it has properties of some other class types too and those classes are mapped to other tables in the database.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I updated the question, Sorry for being dummy I didn't use Entity frame work too much !

Comment: Looks like when you do serialization the child properties initializing from the db but since the db context is already closed it is throwing error.